# How to await on a NGXS action completion?

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, ngxs

I'm using NGXS to manage my state.

For some actions that will take some time(upload an image to firebase, update the entry with the URL), I would like to be able to display some spinner.

Here is the action in my state:

```
  @Action(EditImageAction)
  async editTripImage(ctx: StateContext<TripsStateModel>, action: EditImageAction) {
    const state = ctx.getState();
    const result = await this.cloudStorageService.uploadCameraImage(
      action.photo,
      `/trip/${state.activeTrip}/coverImage`
    );

    const coverUrl = await result.downloadUrl$.toPromise();
    const trip = state.trips.filter((item: Trip) => item.id === state.activeTrip)[0];
    let newTrip = { ...trip, coverImageUrl: coverUrl };
    await this.tripsFirestore.update$(trip.id, newTrip);

  }
```

And here is how I'm trying to call it:

```
        const image = await this.GetImage();

        const loading = await this.loadingController.create();
        await loading.present();
        await this.store.dispatch(new EditImageAction(image)).toPromise();

        const toast = await this.toastController.create({
          message: 'Trip cover changed',
          duration: 2000,
        });
        await toast.present();
        (await loading).dismiss();
```

The code works(I mean, everything is updated on the cloud, synchronized and everything), but the `loading` and the `toast` are just flashing, and after some time(like 1s) I finally see the update of the picture.

If I do the same directly inside my state action, it works properly.

In my mind, deciding to display a toast/loading spinner is a view concern, not a state management concern. I mean, I could call the same action but want different feedback depending on where I'm calling it.

So, how to await on an action to make something after?

Comment: I see multiple `toPromise()`s. Beware it's [being deprecated](https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated) in RxJS 7 and will be gone in RxJS 8. Instead I prefer to convert the promises to observables using RxJS `from`. It provides more granularity in controlling the flow of data in a stream. For eg. you could start the toast message and the loading spinner before the subscription and close them using `finalize` operator.

Comment: @MichaelD Thanks for the info. I love the async/await synthax, very readable. What would be the way to use them if toPromise gets deprecated? I understand the interest of Observable in some cases(particularly when mapping stuff), but otherwise, I find this synthax ugly and not easy to read.

Comment: I understand you're used to Promises and prefer it over Observables. But TBH, observables offer more advantages compared to Promises in fact there's a proposal to include it in [ECMAScript standard](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-observable). Also clean syntax is a matter of perspective. Async/Await paradigm might look non-readable to someone who is more used to observables.

Comment: As for the alternatives to `toPromise()` they are listed in the link I've posted in the original comment.

Comment: @MichaelD Sorry, didn't see the link at first. I guess I will go with the `lastValueFrom` then. I find it less object oriented(and less editor friendly, but ok). Just to be sure: It won't help with the issue I declared?
(what I don't like with the observable is that VS code alway struggle to import them, you have to know exactly the name of what operator you need because you can't discover it with vs code). And importing methods from some packages doesn't feel natural to me as a .Net dev ;)

Comment: Maybe the reason your toastr doesn't wait for action completion is that you don't return anything from action, so your code doesn't know, when some asynchronous operation is finished. Try `return this.tripsFirestore.update$(trip.id, newTrip);`

Comment: Import statements is again a moot point. Importing individual functions and operators are standard convention to import only the specific respective functions/operators to reduce bloat. You could always do something like `import * as Observable from "rxjs";`. Then VS Code would suggest all available functions from `rxjs`. The same goes for operators: something like `import * as Operators from "rxjs/operators";`. I'd suggest starting [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) if you decide to learn RxJS instead of the official docs. They are more of a reference.

Comment: @vitaliykotov I've tried just to be sure(doesn't change anything), but async/await should ensure that I don't return from this method before all the await are completed.

Comment: @MichaelD Yes, I agree, but having the method directly available on the object doesn't consume anything else, allow you to see directly everything that is possible. The issue is that I don't use RxJS in enough projects, so I learn it, understand it then I fail to remember which operator was doing what. They are some things where it's not a "moot point", like having operator to catch error instead of using try catch which are a language feature. I mean, it's nice to have the option, but it feels like reinventing the wheel ;)

Comment: @J4N: You're not wrong in saying reinventing the wheel. The reactive paradigm in invented to overcome the hurdles of synchronous paradigm and observable is invented to overcome the hurdles of single stream promises. And some new wheel will be invented in the future to overcome the shortcomings of both observables and promises or reactive paradigm altogether. It a matter of updating ourselves. The catch error point isn't a good point seeing promises has it's own `.catch` _function_ unlike the JS standard `try...catch` _blocks_.